# deleting a document by updating it and the problem with unique fields

Tags: mongoose

I have a user schema that has an email field, the email field must be unique.

However, the problem is that when someone wants to delete a user, my code does not actually delete the user, but rather, it sets a field named "_archived" to true.

The problem is that when a user gets 'deleted' (i.e. updated to set the _archived field to true), the email gets reserved for the deleted account. In other words, no body can use that email address afterwards because it's unique.

How to work around this in mongoose?

Comment: I've got an Idea, when deleting a document, I can change the email field value from the email to something like `"theRealEmail@email.com___deleted"`

Comment: Maybe you can create a blacklist scheme where you put the email of the deleted user. Then in registrarion step you can check if the email is in a blacklist. If yes, the user can't use that email if not then continue your registration.

Comment: @Quimbo, there's no need for a black list, you can keep the records in the same collection (ex: the users collection), all you have to do is to mark the document as deleted by updating the document with a new field such as (`deleted: true`). The main question was that I want to allow the usage of the older emails (of the deleted users who were using those emails). nobody answered this question, so what I have predicted is a technique that marks the document as deleted, and updating the email field with the Id of the user on the update as well, (ex: {email: x@email.com #deleted (user_id_here)})

Comment: Ok I understand. It's good that this worked for you. I would define my schema with a boolean isActive field. If the user is marked as deleted I set isActive to false, and would add only the email of a deleted user to a blacklist and check the blacklist in the registration step. Obviously in this field (programming) there are different solutions for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to keep a status field in the user schema.

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.schema({
  email: {
   type: String,
   // Note that I haven't added `unique: true` here. 
   // because that will create an index in the DB. And not a validator.
 },
 status: {
   type: String,
   enum: ['active','deleted'],
   default: 'active'
 }
})
```

Now when you need to create a user you will create it after checking if email already exists.

```js
const isEmailUsed = UserModel.findOne({email:'theRealEmail@email.com'})
if(!isEmailUsed) await UserModel.create({email:'theRealEmail@email.com'})
else throw new Error('email is used')
```

After deleting the user set status to deleted.

```js
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({email:'theRealEmail@email.com', status: 'deleted'})
```

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You have `index:true` in the user schema for email?

Comment: @user_shubham yes